# How to extend parent __init__ when child uses more arguments than parent in python

Tags: python, oop, arguments, init

For example I got Link class:

```
class link(object):
    def __init__(self, url, title, visited=False):
        self.url = url
        self.title = title
        self.visited = visited
```

and I want to extend it to ArticleLink class that has one more field - date (pseudocode) :

```
class articleLink(link):
    def __init__(self,<i want to avoid typing it all again>, date):
        super(articleLink, self).__init__(<what to type here?>)
        self.date = date
```

What am I thinking wrong / how to do it properly?

Comment: You have numerous options (e.g. using `*args` and `**kwargs`), but I think it's best to just be explicit and type them out.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```python
# Note this function requires exactly three arguments
def my_method(x,y,z):
    print 'x: %s, y: %s, z: %s'

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, *my_args ):
        my_method( *my_args )


myClass = MyClass( 'x', 'y', 'z' )
# will print "x: x, y: y, z:z"
```

But this is somewhat cryptic.